# Java: what is the overhead of using ConcurrentSkipList* when no concurrency is needed?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, collections, concurrency

I need a sorted list in a scenario dominated by iteration (compared to insert/remove, not random get at all). For this reason I thought about using a skip list compared to a tree (the iterator should be faster).

The problem is that java6 only has a concurrent implementation of a skip list, so I was guessing whether it makes sense to use it in a non-concurrent scenario or if the overhead makes it a wrong decision.

For what I know ConcurrentSkipList* are basically lock-free implementations based on CAS, so they should not carry (much) overhead, but I wanted to hear somebody else's opinion.

EDIT:

After some micro-benchmarking (running iteration multiple times on different-sized TreeSet, LinkedList, ConcurrentSkipList and ArrayList) shows that there's quite an overhead. ConcurrentSkipList does store the elements in a linked list inside, so the only reason why it would be slower on iteration than a LinkedList would be due to the aforementioned overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use a lot of other structures to do the skip list, it exists in Concurrent package because concurrent data structures are a lot more complicated and because using a concurrent skip list would cost less than using other concurrent data structures to mimic a skip list.

In a single thread world is different: you can use a sorted set, a binary tree or your custom data structure that would perform better than concurrent skip list.

The complexity in iterating a tree list or a skip list will be always O(n), but if you instead use a linked list or an array list, you have the problem with insertion: to insert an item in the right position (sorted linked list) the complexity of insertion will be O(n) instead of O(log n) for a binary tree or for a skip list.

You can iterate in TreeMap.keySet() to obtain all inserted keys in order and it will not be so slow.

There is also the TreeSet class, that probably is what you need, but since it is just a wrapper to TreeMap, the direct use of TreeMap would be faster.

Comment: well, the question is exactly what structure to use. I need something that keeps the natural order of the elements, something like the TreeSet, but TreeSet is quite poor as far as iteration is concerned (a linkedlist would be just perfect). LinkedHashSet would be perfect but it sorts by insertion order, not natural ordering of the elements.

Comment: Inserting an item in a linked list mantaining order is O(n) so it's slower, a tree requires O(n log n). Iterating a tree is slower than iterating a list, but not so slower, the difference is constant. Are you sure a tree is not enough? It would be faster than iterating a concurrent skip list.

Comment: from my microbenchmarks it looks like treeset is somehow a bit slower than concurrentskiplist on iteration, but still both are way too slow compared to ArrayList (of course). So in the end I'll wrap ArrayList with a new addSorted() method that does a sorted insert into the ArrayList. The ratio between inserts and iteration in my scenario weights A LOT towards iteration, so it's fine, and the dataset is quite small anyways.

Comment: Good: Arrays are usually faster when number of items is small, of course. When number of items gets large other data structures are absolutely faster :) Thank you for sharing your report.

Comment: Since when is binary tree insertion O(n*log n)?

Answer (score 3):

If thread-safety's not required I'd say to skip `package java.util.concurrent` altogether.

> What's interesting is that sometimes ConcurrentSkipList is slower than TreeSet on the same input and I haven't sorted out yet why.

I mean, have you seen the source code for ConcurrentSkipListMap? :-)  I always have to smile when I look at it. It's 3000 lines of some of the most insane, scary, and at the same time beautiful code I've ever seen in Java. (Kudos to Doug Lea and co. for getting all the concurrency utils integrated so nicely with the collections framework!) Having said that, on modern CPUs the code and algorithmic complexity won't even matter so much. What usually makes more difference is having the data to iterate co-located in memory, so that the CPU cache can do its job better.

> So in the end I'll wrap ArrayList with a new addSorted() method that does a sorted insert into the ArrayList.

Sounds good. If you really need to squeeze every drop of performance out of iteration you could also try iterating a raw array directly. Repopulate it upon each change, e.g. by calling `TreeSet.toArray()` or generating it then sorting it in-place using `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`. But the gain could be tiny (or even nothing if the JIT does its job well) so it might not be worth the inconvenience.

Comment: good idea about the toArray(), i should try that one as well.

Comment: +1 for your point that algorithmic complexity only matters in structures too big for your cache. On the same token, I'm not crazy about using TreeSet.toArray(). Constructing a new TreeSet is _likely_ to stay entirely in your cache, but if it doesn't, you take twice the number of hits from going to main memory.

Answer (score 3):

As measured using Open JDK 6 on typical production hardware my company uses, you can expect all add and query operations on a skip-list map to take roughly *double* the time as the same operation on a tree map.

examples:

63 usec vs 31 usec to create and add 200 entries.
145 ns vs 77 ns for get() on that 200-element map.

And the ratio doesn't change all that much for smaller and larger sizes.

(The code for this benchmark will eventually be shared so you can review it and run it yourself; sorry we're not ready to do that yet.)

Comment: as i said, i could imagine that to happen, the thing is that i'm willing to get a slightly higher cost in add when I get improvement in iteration.

Comment: ookay, just answering the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Without concurrency, it is usually more efficient to use a balanced binary search tree. In Java, this would be a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Skip lists are generally reserved for concurrent programming because of their ease in implementation the speed in multithreaded applications.

Comment: as i mentioned in the other answer, Tree* iterators are not as efficient as linked list, so I doubt using a Tree would be a good idea in a scenario dominated by iteration like mine.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a good grasp of the trade-off here, so I doubt anyone can give you a definitive, principled answer. Fortunately, this is pretty straightforward to test.

I started by creating a simple `Iterator<String>` that loops indefinitely over a finite list of randomly generated strings. (That is: on initialization, it generates an array `_strings` of *a* random strings of length *b* out of a pool of *c* distinct characters. The first call to `next()` returns `_strings[0]`, the next call returns `_strings[1]` … the (*n*+1)th call returns `_strings[0]` again.) The strings returned by this iterator were what I used in all calls to `SortedSet<String>.add(...)` and `SortedSet<String>remove(...)`.

I then wrote a test method that accepts an empty `SortedSet<String>` and loops *d* times. On each iteration, it adds *e* elements, then removes *f* elements, then iterates over the entire set. (As a sanity-check, it keeps track of the set's size by using the return values of `add()` and `remove()`, and when iterates over the entire set, it makes sure it finds the expected number of elements. Mostly I did that just so there would be *something* in the body of the loop.)

I don't think I need to explain what my `main(...)` method does. :-)

I tried various values for the various parameters, and I found that sometimes `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>` performed better, and sometimes `TreeSet<String>` did, but the difference was never much more than twofold. In general, `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>` performed better when:

- *a*, *b*, and/or *c* were relatively large. (I mean, within the ranges I tested. My *a*'s ranged from 1000 to 10000, my *b*'s from 3 to 10, my *c*'s from 10 to 80. Overall, the resulting set-sizes ranged from around 450 to exactly 10000, with modes of 666 and 6666 because I usually used *e*=2‎*f*.) This suggests that `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>` copes somewhat better than `TreeSet<String>` with larger sets, and/or with more-expensive string-comparisons. Trying specific values designed to tease apart these two factors, I got the impression that `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>` coped noticeably better than `TreeSet<String>` with larger sets, and slightly *less* well with more-expensive string-comparisons. (That's basically what you'd expect; `TreeSet<String>`'s binary-tree approach aims to do the absolute minimum possible number of comparisons.)
- *e* and *f* were small; that is, when I called `add(...)`s and `remove(...)`s only a small number of times per iteration. (This is exactly what you predicted.) The exact turn-over point depended on *a*, *b*, and *c*, but to a first approximation, `ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>` performed better when *e* + *f* was less than around 10, and `TreeSet<String>` performed better when *e* + *f* was more than around 20.

Of course, this was on a machine that may look nothing like yours, using a JDK that may look nothing like yours, and using very artificial data that might look nothing like yours. I'd recommend that you run your own tests. Since `Tree*` and `ConcurrentSkipList*` both implement `Sorted*`, you should have no difficulty trying your code both ways and seeing what you find.

> For what I know ConcurrentSkipList* are basically lock-free implementations based on CAS, so they should not carry (much) overhead, […]

My understanding is that this will depend on the machine. On some systems a lock-free implementation may not be possible, in which case these classes will have to use locks. (But since you're not actually multi-threading, even locks may not be *all* that expensive. Synchronization has overhead, of course, but its *main* cost is lock contention and forced single-threading. That isn't an issue for you. Again, I think you'll just have to test and see how the two versions perform.)

Comment: thanks for the insightful answer. As a matter of fact I ran a similar test and my results are exactly like yours. What's interesting is that sometimes ConcurrentSkipList is slower than TreeSet on the same input and I haven't sorted out yet why.

Answer (score 0):

As noted SkipList has a lot of overhead compared to TreeMap and the TreeMap iterator isn't well suited to your use case because it just repeatedly calls the method successor() which turns out to be very slow.
So one alternative that will be significantly faster than the previous two is to write your own TreeMap iterator.  Actually, I would dump TreeMap altogether since 3000 lines of code is a bit bulkier than you probably need and just write a clean AVL tree implementation with the methods you need.  The basic AVL logic is just a [few hundred lines of code in any language](https://github.com/dmcmanam/kelleysisland/blob/master/avltree.go) then add the iterator that works best in your case.